# How do I prove that group determined by generators and relations is trivial?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

I have a group $\langle a,b\mid a^4=b^2=1, ab^2=b^3a, ba^3=a^2b\rangle $ how do I show that it's trivial?

Comment: By proving that every element in the group is equal to the unit element.

Comment: I understand that, but what do this relations give me to prove that?

Comment: Well, play with the relations.  Since $b^2=e$ we have $a=ba$ so...

Comment: is it true that if $a=ba$ then $b=e$?

Comment: @AlexanderKraynov Well, you pose a zero-effort very broad question, you should expect a zero-effort very broad answer.

Comment: @AlexanderKraynov $a=ba$, multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$ on the right would give $e=b$

Comment: i get it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a=ab^2=b^3a \implies b^3=1$. Then $b^2=1$ and $b^3=1$ imply that $b=1$. Then $ba^3=a^2b \implies a^3=a^2 \implies a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $b^2=1$,$$ab^2=b^3a\implies a=ba\implies b=1$$Then using this, $$ba^3=a^2b\implies a^3=a^2\implies a=1$$